# Heroku CLI install failing Mac OSX

Tags: macos, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Randomly my heroku toolbelt stopped working. I'm not sure why, but when I execute any heroku action, for example `heroku -v` this happens:

```
➜  Homebrew heroku -v
heroku-cli: Adding dependencies... 2.57 MB/2.57 MB
2016/04/26 12:13:42 running npm from /Users/cowan/.heroku: /Users/cowan/.heroku/node-5.10.1-darwin-amd64/node /Users/cowan/.heroku/npm-3.8.5/cli.js -v --loglevel=info
ERROR: expected npm  to equal v5.10.1
```

Note this particular example is after I used homebrew to uninstall and reinstall heroku.

Comment: as the error says you should update your npm first

Comment: @uDaY according to https://github.com/npm/npm/releases the latest release is 3.8.8, but heroku is asking for v5.10.1?

Comment: sorry I mean node version...can you see whats the node version?

Comment: @uDaY I'm using v5.10.1, and the most recent is v5.11, but I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in 2 steps:

1. Fresh install from https://toolbelt.heroku.com/osx
2. Restart bash/zsh

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that there's a built-in update command:

```
heroku update
```

(I was trying to update via homebrew until I realised I didn't need to and just ran `heroku update` instead).

I found it via `heroku --help`